# I set up my public node to use port 18089, but why does monerod keep trying to connect to port 18081?

Tags: monerod, full-node, nodes

I have a VPS and would like to run a public node and get it indexed by moneroworld to help the network.

I made the necessary changes to `monerod.conf` to change the port to 18089 and to restrict things to keep people from mining on my system. But whenever I use monerod to check the status, it keeps trying to connect to port 18081. 
See screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

My node is currently running (209.159.146.140:18089) and I can connect to it directly using wallets on different systems just fine. But I keep getting the above error when running `monerod status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default config file location is actually in `~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.conf`, so if you are using another location, you need to start the daemon with `--config-file /etc/monerod.conf` in your case.

Or if your domain is, as you say, already running on the port 18089, to run the status command you would need to:

`monerod status --rpc-bind-port 18089`

Comment: When I created a service definition for monerod.service, I included the path to the config file:  

`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/monerod --config-file /etc/monerod.conf  --detach --pidfile /run/monero/monerod.pid`  

Running `monerod status --rpc-bind-port 18089` worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I configured my monero node following this guide https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-xmr/guide-or-how-to-run-a-full-node
and there also is recommended to use port 18089
But after that I could see that this is not the default port (18081)
So why to change from 18081 to 18089 ???
Regards.